# Sharing a business notebook with Evernote API

Tags: c#, evernote

I'm getting a `Evernote.EDAM.Error.EDAMErrorCode.PERMISSION_DENIED` error on createSharedNotebook when trying to share a business notebook.

```
AuthenticationResult busAuthResult = _userStore.authenticateToBusiness(authToken);
var bAuthToken = busAuthResult.AuthenticationToken;
var bNoteStoreUri = busAuthResult.NoteStoreUrl;
TTransport noteStoreTransport = new THttpClient(new Uri(bNoteStoreUri));
TProtocol noteStoreProtocol = new TBinaryProtocol(noteStoreTransport);
var noteStore = new NoteStore.Client(noteStoreProtocol);
var notebook = noteStore.getNotebook(bAuthToken, notebookGuid);

var sharedNotebook = new SharedNotebook();
sharedNotebook.Email = "test@test.com";
sharedNotebook.NotebookModifiable = true;
sharedNotebook.AllowPreview = true;
sharedNotebook.NotebookGuid = notebookGuid;

noteStore.createSharedNotebook(bAuthToken, sharedNotebook);
```

The account I'm using has access to share the notebook, so I can't figure out where this error is coming from. I haven't been able to find anything on sharing business notebooks, so any ideas or links would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I assume you are getting EDAMUserException (https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/Errors.html#Struct_EDAMUserException). What is the parameter in it?

Comment: Exception of type 'Evernote.EDAM.Error.EDAMUserException' was thrown.

Comment: The parameter is authenticationToken

Comment: You're sure the exception is being thrown from createSharedNotebook, not from getNotebook, right?

Comment: Yes, it throws the error on the createSharedNotebook. The only reason I include the getNotebook line is to show that notebook I'm trying to share is valid and accessible by the business account.

Answer (score 0):

I think `NotebookModifiable` is deprecated. Instead, can you add `privilege`? After that, hopefully you would get another error message that tell you exactly what other parameters like `recipientSettings` you have to add.